# JAR Missing on Java Project

Tags: java, jar

I've Googled a lot trying to find the jar that contains the following clasess:

```
import com.zerog.ia.api.pub.CustomCodeAction;
import com.zerog.ia.api.pub.InstallerProxy;
import com.zerog.ia.api.pub.UninstallerProxy;
```

Any idea of where can I find it?

Tks.

Answer (score 3):

This is from a commercial product from a company called [Flexera Software](http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/robo/projects/ia2011api/javadoc/com/zerog/ia/api/pub/CustomCodeAction.html).  BTW, you can use the java [package naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html#28840) to find the information about a jar.  It is usually starts with the reverse of the url of the company or organization that produced it.  In this case, it was zerog.com, but that now forwards to Flexera.

Comment: OK, but do you know how can I get this jar?

Comment: It's a commercial product.  You either have to purchase it or use the trial version.

Answer (score 2):

You need import this library: **IAClasses.zip**

Location: 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallAnywhere 2012\resource\IAClasses.zip"

CustomCodeAction, InstallerProxy and UninstallerProxy class location here:
 "IAClasses.zip\com\zerog\ia\api\pub\"

Answer (score 1):

The jar you're looking for belongs to a Java installer product named InstallAnywhere, originally made by Zero G Software. Zero G was bought up by Macrovision, who then sold their software group to Flexera Software.

Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a community edition.

Comment: OK, but do you know how can I get this jar?

Comment: Go to http://www.flexerasoftware.com and request an evaluation license, I suppose. Once you have an evaluation license I guess you can download the jar(s).